# stddef.h |212|error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘typedef’

Tags: c

The code does not compile. But I run it altogether in one file it does. It tells me:

stddef.h   |212|error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘typedef’

What's really going on?

Main.c File:

```
#include "InvMatriz.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
float **A;
int n;
printf("Ingrese el tamaño de la matriz: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

A = ingresematriz(n);
mostrarmatriz(A, n);
printf("adfasd");

return 0;
}
```

Header File InvMatriz.h

```
#ifndef INVMATRIZ_H_
#define INVMATRIZ_H_

float** ingresematriz(int );
void mostrarmatriz(float**X ,int x);

#endif // INVMATRIZ_H
```

Ingrese Matriz.c File

```
#include "InvMatriz.h"
#include <stdio.h>



float **ingresematriz(int n)
{

int i, j;

//Asigna espacio en la memoria

float **A;

A = malloc(n * sizeof (float *));
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    *(A + i) = malloc(n * sizeof(float));
}

//Pide los elementos y los guarda

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        printf("Elemento [%d] [%d]:  ", i + 1, j + 1);
        scanf("%f", *(A + i) + j);
    }
}
return A;
}
```

Mostrar Matriz.c File

```
#include "InvMatriz.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void mostrarmatriz(float **X , int x) //Porque no hace nada pero si compila?
{

int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < x; j++)
    {
        printf("%f        ", *(*(X + i) + j));
    }
    printf("\n");


}
}
```

Comment: Post your compiler output, and the command you use to compile this. Hopefully we can at least see which of your .c file it fails to compile.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you swap the order in which you include the headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "InvMatriz.h"
```

That may not fix the problem as such - it may hide it, but either way it will likely change the diagnostics in a way that may help you focus on the real problem.  In general you should always include the system headers ahead of your own in any case.

At a guess I would suggest that you have omitted a newline after:

```
#endif // INVMATRIZ_H
```

If you do that the first line of the next included file will become part of the comment, and that can render the subsequent code invalid.  Most modern compilers will warn of a sourcefile not ending in a blank line.

File inclusion is a simple case of inserting the content of one file in another and an error in one header can be reported in the subsequently included header.  No doubt stddef.h is the first file included by stdio.h.  When you *"run it altogether in one file"*, the order of teh code would not have been the same - the content of your header being inserted *after* stdio.h rather than before.

Comment: Comments cannot continue across file boundaries in a standard-compliant compiler.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : I think that deserves a citation.  It is certainly indirectly true of C++11 that implicitly inserts a newline after non-empty includes that do not have one. from C99 5.1.1.2 has *"A source file that is not empty shall end in a new-line character, which shall not be immediately preceded by a backslash character before any such splicing takes place."*.  What C11 does is perhaps a moot point. In the end your compiler does what it does - complaining about ISO compliance is not going to get work done.

Comment: The relevant citation is ISO/IEC 9899:2011, §5.1.1.2 **Translation phases**, ¶3 _The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens and sequences of
white-space characters (including comments). A source file shall not end in a
partial preprocessing token or in a partial comment._  (I've omitted a reference to footnote 7 as it isn't germane, and you can't do superscripts in comments.)  The larger context for the quote indicates that this applies individually to each file that is part of a translation unit.